# Canvas on backbone js View rendering / reloading only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, canvas

Here is my situation
I am trying to create a View which contains just a canvas to capture signature.
When I run the code for the first time I am able to draw on the canvas.
But when I go to another page and come back to the signature page, the canvas is visible, but the drawing is not happening.

I scanned the code and the problem seems to happen in the line

rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

My rect.left, rect.top, rect.bottom, rect.right all return 0, whereas only at the first time of run they show 15, 84, 415, 384

I've set the canvas width and height as 400 and 300

I have attached my code

```
var canvas;
var context;
var radius = 2;
var dragging = false;
var targetTouch;
var rect;

var SignatureView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "touchstart #SignCanvas": "engage",
    "touchmove #SignCanvas": "putPoint",
    "touchend #SignCanvas": "disengage"
  },

  //Compile and assign the template
  template: getTemplate("signature"),

  initialize: function () {
    this.render();
  },

  //Render the contents
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    this.delegateEvents();
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.prepSignPad()
    }, 0);
    return this;
  },

  prepSignPad: function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("SignCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.lineWidth = radius * 2;
  },

  updateStatus: function() {
    this.$("#divStatusbar").html("Canvas Loaded");
  },

  putPoint: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    targetTouch = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];

    rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    var x = targetTouch.pageX - rect.left;
    var y = targetTouch.pageY - rect.top;

    if(dragging) {
      context.lineTo(x, y);
      context.stroke();
      context.fillStyle = "black";
      context.beginPath();

      context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.fill();
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x, y);
    }
  },

  engage: function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    putPoint(e);
  },

  disengage: function() {
    dragging = false;
    context.beginPath();
  }

});
```

This SignatureView gets called in the below-mentioned DOrderView

```
var DOrderView = Backbone.View.extend({

  //Compile and assign the template
  template: getTemplate("DOrder"),
  initialize: function () {
    this.$el.attr('data-role', 'page');
    this.render();
    this.updateStatus();
  },

  //Render the contents
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
  //if(!this.view) {
    this.view = new SignatureView();
  //}

    this.$("#divSignature").append(this.view.el);
    this.view.delegateEvents();
    return this;
  },

  updateStatus: function() {
    this.$("#divStatusbar").html("Delivered Order (DO)");
  }

});
```

Thank you. I tried editing the code the way you suggested. I'm sure it should work, but for some reason it is not working. Here's what I first tried after your suggestion

```
var DOrderView = Backbone.View.extend({

//Compile and assign the template
    template: getTemplate("DOrder"),

    initialize: function () {
  this.$el.attr('data-role', 'page');
  this.render();
  this.updateStatus();
},

    //Render the contents
    render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());

  if(this.SignatureView) {
    this.SignatureView.remove();
  }

  this.SignatureView = new SignatureView();

  this.$("#divSignature").append(this.SignatureView.el);
  this.SignatureView.delegateEvents();
    },

updateStatus: function() {
  this.$("#divStatusbar").html("Delivered Order (DO)");
}
```

Could that be because the parent view DOrderView might not have been destroyed?

But then I ended up tweaking the code as below and it works now!

```
var DOrderView = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
          "click .back, #btnHome": "close"
},

//Compile and assign the template
    template: getTemplate("DOrder"),

    initialize: function () {
  this.$el.attr('data-role', 'page');
  this.render();
  this.updateStatus();
},

    //Render the contents
    render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());
  this.SignatureView = new SignatureView();

  this.$("#divSignature").append(this.SignatureView.el);
    },

updateStatus: function() {
  this.$("#divStatusbar").html("Delivered Order (DO)");
},

close: function() {
  this.SignatureView.unbind();
  this.SignatureView.remove();
}

});
```

Please let me know if you think this approach could cause any issues down the line?

Many thanks for your time. Appreciate it!

Comment: The code above looks good. When you "leave the page and come back", are you destroying the view and creating another? I believe the relevant code is in the view implementation, not the view itself.

Comment: jsibales, Thank you for responding to my question. Can you please let me know how to destroy and recreate the view? Should I do this in the view (where I am instantiating it for the first time)?

Comment: I would be happy to show you some example code. How are you currently creating the view?

Comment: I pasted the code as an answer tab as I didnt know how to paste the code in a comment. Hope you can see it below

Comment: You should add the code as an edit to your original question. Under the tag listing for your questions is a link to "edit". Paste your code in there.

Comment: I just did. Hope you can see it now.

Comment: Looks good. Cleaned up a little and placed my solution below. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again, I just edited my code and showed you the resulting behaviors. Hope you can look at it. It worked after I tweaked your suggestions a bit.

Comment: NP... Just updated my answer with another idea to consider. You don't have to accept the answer, but throw me some rep with an upvote if you don't mind =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, you need to make sure you destroy the view before each render. So in your `DOrderView`'s render method, we should first destroy the old view before creating the new view. You were almost there, just missing a line:

```
//Render the contents
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());

  // The following code block will check if there is already a SignatureView
  // and if there is one, will call the View's `remove()` method. The `remove()`
  // method call's BackboneView's native `stopListening()` method as well as 
  // jQuery's `remove()` method on the view element. 
  if(this.view) {
    this.view.remove(); 
  }

  // Now we will create a fresh view on every render
  this.view = new SignatureView();
  this.$("#divSignature").append(this.view.el);
  this.view.delegateEvents();
  return this;
}
```

### Update:

The approach you stumbled upon is EXACTLY how I implement in my Backbone Views. Its a little opinionated, so I didn't want to throw you in that direction right off the bat. Glad you found your way there. For added points, you can create a base View that includes the close method by default so you don't have to add the method to each new view:

```
var myBaseView = Backbone.View.extend({

  close: function () {
    this.unbind();
    this.remove();
  }

});
```

And then you can use it like:

```
var myNewExtendedView = myBaseView.extend({

  // Define custom view logic that extends off of base here. This view will come
  // preloaded with the close method. Sweeeeeet.

});
```

Comment: Awesome! That was an excellent suggestion. Now (this being my first time) lemme see how I should accept and upvote this answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Wouldn't allow me to upvote as my reputation hasn't reached 15 points yet :-(. But certainly your answer is accepted and proves right to the situation I was struggling with

Comment: No worries... a few more questions and maybe an answer or two from you and you'll be able to start up/down voting with the rest of the community